# Javascript scale check function performance

Tags: javascript, performance, math, loops, exponent

All right people, I've got a slight performance bottle neck.

Basically I have a graph that consists of a screen div ("screen") and a chart div ("chart"), when this graph finishes rendering it checks to see what scale it needs to set on the chart in order to have the chart fit inside the screen. The problem is that whatever scale I come up with needs to be an exponent of 1.2. In other words you need to be able to get to the number of the new scale by taking 1.2 to the power of some number.

This function is what calculates the scale I need.

```
fitScale = function (width, height)
{
  var scale = 1,
      gWidth = graph.element.offsetWidth,
      gHeight = graph.element.offsetHeight;
  while (gWidth > width * scale && gHeight > height * scale)
    scale *= 1.2;
  while (gWidth < width * scale || gHeight < height * scale)
    scale /= 1.2;
  return 900 / scale;
}
```

The problem is that this sucks...

What it's doing is getting the chart size (`width, height`) and the screen size (`gWidth, gHeight`) and looping through a new scale until it hits the right number.

First it makes the scale bigger until at least one dimension of the chart times the scale is bigger than one dimension of the screen.

Than it loops back to make sure that both the dimensions of chart * scale are at least a little bit smaller than the screen.

I'de like to perform this action with just one math calculation. Maybe by calculating a snug fit and then by rounding down, but I can't figure out how to round down to an exponent of 1.2

-fix-

Here's the resulting working version...

```
fitScale = function (width, height)
{
  var wScale = graph.element.offsetWidth / width,
      hScale = graph.element.offsetHeight / height,
      snugg = wScale < hScale ? wScale : hScale,
      exp = Math.log(snugg) / Math.log(1 / 1.2),
      scale = Math.pow(1 / 1.2, Math.ceil(exp));
  return 900 / scale;
}
```

Comment: This is why god made logarithms and Brendan Eich made the `log` function.

Comment: Yes but how would I use them?

Comment: Well hell, that looks right. I knew there had to be a way. Why do more people not know how to do this?

Comment: So how do I use a log function to find my scale?

Comment: http://www.regentsprep.org/Regents/math/algtrig/ATE8/exponentialEquations.htm

Comment: But finding the natural logarithm is not that helpful to me.

Comment: How did you come to the value 1.2?

Comment: I picked a value, what happens is whenever someone uses the mouse wheel the graph scales in and out, 1.2 seemed like a nice fit. But whenever the scale is just set to some number, it needs to be a number times the multiplier I use. That way the user can scroll in or out and the multiplier will take them back to a scale of 1 at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My math skills are rusty, so go easy if I wander off the Path of Truth here.

Basically you want to know what power `y` of `1.2` is equal to some given number `x`. While the `log` function would appear not to be helpful since it tells you what power of `e` will equal your number `x`, with some mad logarithm skillz you can in fact use that to get to where you want to go:

```
var y = Math.log(x) / Math.log(1.2);
```

Odds are pretty good that `y` won't be a whole number which is I think what you want, so if you just go ahead and `Math.floor(y)`, you should be all set.